# MSSQL 2008: вопрос по временным таблицам и табличным переменным

Tags: база-данных, sql-server

**Добрый день!**

Решаю задачу:

Хранимая процедура выполняет другую, которая передается как параметр в нее, и получает результирующую таблицу. Т.к. разные хранимки дергают разные таблицы, набор колонок у нас всегда разный.  Можно ли как-то во временную таблицу или табличную переменную (не указывая набор колонок в ней, т.к. они всегда разные) положить результирущую таблицу? Или может есть какое-то более элегантное решение?

Благодарю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

так делать не стоит - переданная вам сохраненная процедура может вернуть и несколько наборов записей, в том числе с разными полями. лучше в зависимости от выраженного именем процедуры режима делать разные insert exec.

Answer (score 1):

Если я Вас правильно понял, то вы выполняете разные селекты, но хотите чтобы они укладывались в одну таблицу. Если то то вам подйодет такая конструкция:

```
SELECT
   --Список полей
INTO
   ResultTable
FROM
   SourceTable
...
```

Если таблицы `ResultTable` не существует, то она создаться с набором колонок из `SELECT`