# MSSQL: как выполнить произвольный код, который передается в функцию строкой

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

упрощаем: 
имеется переменная:

```
DECLARE @A = 'SELECT A,B,C FROM TableName ORDER BY A'
```

Создаем функцию, в которой этот код из переменной выше должен выполняться:
CREATE FUNCTION fnReturnTable.....

а в коде процедуры нужно выполнить код, заданный в переменной [[[@A](/users/967/aghasalim)](/users/967/aghasalim)](/users/967/aghasalim)  и вернуть результат (таблицу).

Я пробую это делать так:

```
EXEC(@A)
```

И мне выдается ошибка: неправильный синтаксис возле слова EXEC.

**Как можно выполнить код из той переменной, и при этом чтобы результат как таблица вернулся из этой функции? Спасибо.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в функции нельзя выполнить exec, кроме как для вызова extended stored procedures.

Comment: вас понял. вопрос тогда в другом: 
как можно присвоить результат выполнения EXEC(@A) или табл. переменную, и при этом не указывая в ней колонки? В моем случае,мы не знаем имена колонок, который нам вернет EXEC(@A), т.к. код формируется динамически.

Comment: формировать код для создания или модификации временной таблицы одновременно с вашим куском кода. но лучше так не делать - injection никто не отменял, а дыр в защите от него вы можете наплодить много.

Answer (score 1):

Начну с того, что я согласен с @maxleo - такое делать не стоит без особых на то причин.

А теперь по делу.

В Вашем примере пропущено объявление типа переменной `@A`. Вот такое вполне работает на MS SQL Server 2008:

```
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * FROM SomeTable;';

EXEC (@Query);
```

Так же есть такая хранимая процедура [sp_ExecuteSQL](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188001.asp). При успешном выполнении она вернет 0, иначе код ошибки:

```
DECLARE @result INT;

EXEC @result = sp_ExecuteSQL @Query;

PRINT @result;
```

И, если то что я написал выше с [моим же ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/281003/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-mssql-2008-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC/281010) на еще один Ваш вопрос, то можно сделать что-то такое:

```
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * INTO NewTable FROM SomeTable;';
EXEC (@Query);
```

И уже работать с полученной таблицей `NewTable`.

Comment: Ну, я тоже покомментирую:

Во-первых, sp_executesql сама по себе не может сохранить результат во временную таблицу с помощью insert exec. еще хуже, если для получения результата тоже требуется insert exec - тогда только создавать временную таблицу, а вставку осуществлять с помощью переданной в sp_executesql команды. 

Во-вторых, у исполняющего команды пользователя обычно нет прав на создание таблиц (а часто и прямого доступа к данным в таблицах), так что только select into #временная_таблица.

ЗЫ: он-то хотел сделать все в функции, а это без привлечения CLR или xp совсем невозможно.

Comment: @maxleo, и правда - временную не создает. Я вот обычную вполне. А вот на счет прав пользователей - если ТС такое задумал, то должен и права на это кому надо дать

Comment: временную тоже создает, только при смене контекста она заканчивается. фокус в том, чтобы создать временную таблицу заранее. я выше опечатался - имел в виду insert select #временная_таблица.